# Recurse through subdirectories and rename all files of a given extension the same filename

Tags: bash, rename

This should be simple but I am getting stuck somewhere.

I want to recurse through a directory and rename all pdfs the same filename. The renamed files should remain in their current subdirectory.

The current PDF filenames are arbitrary.

Assume that I am running this script from the top directory. Inside this top directory are several subdirs, each with a PDF with an arbitrary filename.

This works to rename the files in place:

`find . -iname "*.pdf" -exec rename 's/test.pdf/commonname.pdf/' '{}' \;`

But since the current filenames are arbitrary, I need to swap out a regex for "any characters or digits" in place of `test.pdf`

My understanding is that the correct regex expression is `.*`

So I tried:

`find . -iname "*.pdf" -exec rename 's/.*/commonname.pdf/' '{}' \;`

When I run this, the first PDF gets renamed to commonpdf.pdf, but it is moved into the top directory. My use case requires that the PDFs get renamed in place.

I am missing something obvious here, clearly - can you spot my mistake?

Comment: `find . -iname "*.pdf" -execdir mv \{\} commonname.pdf \;` ?

Comment: Look at the output of `-exec echo {} \;` – you'll see that `{}` contains the complete path, like `/path/to/file.pdf`, and with `.*` you replace everything including the path, not just the filename. If you have GNU `find`, @Shawn's method is a good solution: `-execdir` sets the working directory to the directory containing the matching file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `s/.*/commonname.pdf/`, `.*` matches the complete path, not just the filename. You could make sure that the regular expression applies to nothing but the filename by matching on non-slashes:

```sh
find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec rename 's|[^/]*$|commonname.pdf|' '{}' \;
```

or you could use GNU find's `-execdir`, which sets the working directory to the directory containing the matching file:

```sh
find . -iname '*.pdf' -execdir rename 's/.*/commonname.pdf/' '{}' \;
```

or not use `rename` at all:

```sh
find . -iname '*.pdf' -execdir mv {} commonname.pdf \;
```

or not use `find`, but a single invocation of `rename`:

```sh
rename 's|[^/]*$|commonname.pdf|' **/*.pdf
```

This requires the `globstar` shell option to enable the `**` glob.

Use the `-n` option to `rename` for a dry run without actually changing filenames.